# Access .cab file from CRM 2011 HTML webresource

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, activex, dynamics-crm, cab, activexobject

I have created one .cab file which contains a C# dll and I need to use that as ActiveX control in MSCRM2011 webresource. So, where shall I keep this .cab file, so that it should be accessible in CRM HTML webresource to create ActiveX control?

Comment: Why do you even want to do that. What is your requirement

Comment: We are creating a .prn files in local folder and sending them to the printers using C# code in that dll.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot do this. Dynamics CRM does not support ActiveX controls and you cannot instantiate an ActiveX control in JavaScript, even if you have the binary of the control, so there is no (at least that I know of) workaround.

That said, you are not out of luck. You need to change from using at ActiveX and investigate using Silverlight, which will allow you to directly interact with the local machine. Dynamics CRM supports adding [Silverlight as a Web Resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2011/06/23/how-to-create-a-silverlight-web-resource-that-interacts-with-crm-2011-forms.aspx). I would plan to invest significant time in this as sending a `PRN` file to the print spooler could get tricky from a Silverlight app.